# Image Scale type center crop on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to do something similar to centerCrop property from android ImageView.
Setting the height of the imageview, and making it crop and align to center, just as centerCrop works on android.

```
 Widget bindItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
return new Card(
    child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Image.network(
            _parties[index]["cover"], fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            height: 120.0,
          ),
          new Text(_parties[index]['name'])
        ]
    )
);
```

}

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("Parties"),
            ),
            body: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _parties == null ? 0 : _parties.length,
              itemBuilder: bindItem,
            )
        );
      }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Android ScaleType and BoxFit should match like this:

1. CENTER = none
2. CENTER_CROP = cover
3. CENTER_INSIDE = scaleDown
4. FIT_CENTER = contain (alignment.center)
5. FIT_END = contain  (alignment.bottomright)
6. FIT_START = contain (alignment.topleft)
7. FIT_XY = fill

> **Ex :-** `Image.asset('assets/images/your_image.png',fit: BoxFit.fill)`

So you should use Cover to achieve the CENTER_CROP result.

EDIT:

The problem should be `crossAxisAlignment` of the Column widget.
Setting this property to `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` should fix your issue.

Comment: Can you show me an image of the result and of the expected result? I'm thinking that you have problem with the parent layout and not with the image itself.

Comment: Current output: https://i.snag.gy/FzcX1d.jpg Expected: https://i.snag.gy/MwG7Vb.jpg , when I add the image as the card child it works, but if the card child is a column, to be able to add the text under, is not working anymore.  Everything is under a listview, i've updated my code. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use "crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch" property on the Column widget. I tested it and seems to work.

Answer (score 10):

```
new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(child: new Image.network(
            cover.img,fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),

        ),
        Text(cover.name),
      ]
    )
```

this works for me

Answer (score 4):

```
new Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: new Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/firebase1.png',
                          width: 100.0,
                          height: 100.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: You should explain why 100x100px should work. Out of my view this cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the parent widget with an image you should use (as already pointed out by [Antonino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49121328/995926)) `BoxFit.cover` together with a width and height of `infinity` to consume the space of the parent view.

```dart
Image.network(
  imageUrl,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  width: double.infinity,
  height: double.infinity,
),
```

Comment: You should use this approach only parent has bounded constraints

Answer (score -1):

Please add this following width and height to the image

Note: We are zooming the image

```
height: double.infinity, 
width: double.infinity,`
```